# Symfony 6 base url. Redirect to the public/index.php

Tags: php, apache, symfony, web-development-server, symfony6

I have a symfony 6 application. I used symfony server for development(I regret it now) because I was "recommended". I use xampp so I go to the public (http://localhost:8080/projects/mag6/public/) folder and it goes to the (/) route. But if I go to other routes /login (http://localhost:8080/login) routes it doesn't work. With symfony server I works http://127.0.0.1:8000/ goes to (/) route and http://127.0.0.1:8000/login goes to (login) route. I thought it would be easy to configure the since the symfony is a huge community but I was wrong. I cant find the answer i am looking for on the internet.

Comment: What type of server are you using?

Comment: try `composer require symfony/apache-pack`

Comment: I am using xampp, and have tried thapache-pack but no success

Comment: composer require symfony/apache-pack installs .htaccess file inside the public folder but the behavior of the file system hasn't changed at all.